# Unable to create JMS QueueConnection from QueueConnectionFactory in Jersey2

Tags: jms, message-queue, jersey-2.0

I'm working on migrating my existing EJB application from Jersey 1.x to 2.x. facing many challenges related to EJB and JMS queue concepts. I'm facing an Null pointer exception when the below code is executed.

```
        import javax.jms.Queue;
        import javax.jms.QueueConnection;
        import javax.jms.QueueConnectionFactory;
        import javax.jms.QueueSession;

        public class SessionImpl implements SessionLocal {

          @Resource(mappedName = "java:/RemoteJmsXA")
          private QueueConnectionFactory queueConnectionFactory;
          @Inject
          private ConvRequestSessionLocal convRequestSession;
          private RequestSessionLocal asyncSession;

           @PostConstruct
          public void initialize() {
            QueueConnection connection = null;
            QueueSession queueSession = null;
            try {
              connection = queueConnectionFactory.createQueueConnection();
              queueSession = connection.createQueueSession(true, QueueSession.SESSION_TRANSACTED);
              asyncSession = AsyncUtils.mixinAsync(convRequestSession);
            } catch (JMSException e) {
              LOG.error("Error ocurred while connecting to remote queues. " + e.getLocalizedMessage());
              throw new RuntimeException("Error occured while connecting to remote queues.", e);
            } finally {
              try {
                if (queueSession != null) {
                  queueSession.close();
                }
                if (connection != null) {
                  connection.close();
                }
              } catch (JMSException e) {
                LOG.error("Error occured while closing connection to remote queues. " + e.getLocalizedMessage());
              }
            }
          }

        }
```

Exception:

```
    2017-01-18 20:08:44,317 WARNING [org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors] (http-127.0.0.1-8080-4) The following warnings have been detected: WARNING: Unknown HK2 failure detected:
    MultiException stack 1 of 2
    java.lang.NullPointerException
     at com.ejb.session.impl.SessionImpl.initialize(SessionImpl.java:809)
     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
```

stack trace shows that exception throws exactly in this line 
**connection = queueConnectionFactory.createQueueConnection();**

Comment: Are you using an EE server?

Comment: Yes. My project runs on JBOSS 5 and it features EJB, Hibernate and JPA. Using JMS for messaging service. Queue creation is any different in Jersey 2? please explain.

Comment: @peeskillet any clue on this ?

Comment: No. I don't really work with JMS